# SO Careers - Allow searching for telecommute jobs restricted to a specific country

Tags: feature-request, jobs, search, filtering

Title says it all, really.

I'd really like a way to search for telecommute jobs, but restricted to a specific country.

This is simply because acquiring a telecommuting job in your own country rather than a foreign one is significantly easier for both the employee and employer (think legalities etc.)

Oh, and if the feature is implemented, please ensure that a suitable RSS feed exists to apply the same filtering at RSS level as can be performed via the website.

Comment: +1 for this. However may I suggest being able to restrict it to a particular time zone would also be a nice option (very useful for the Euro zone).