# Can't choose a country as a location

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, location

While updating my careers profile I've noticed that I can't enter country names anymore as locations where I'm willing to relocate to. The problem is that if I'm willing to relocate o a different country, I might not care about the city...

The error I'm receiving when I enter a country name, e.g. Denmark:

> Sorry, we need a more specific location than 'Denmark'. Try again?

If I enter Luxembourg, the entry gets corrected to "Luxembourg City, Luxembourg" which is not what I actually meant.

I don't know how to specify that I would be willing to work anywhere in a country or even a continent.

Comment: However, if you enter "Singapore", since it's a city-state, the country _is_ the city.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I filter jobs on Careers by continent?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123744/can-i-filter-jobs-on-careers-by-continent), [SO Careers - Allow searching for telecommute jobs restricted to a specific country](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124603/so-careers-allow-searching-for-telecommute-jobs-restricted-to-a-specific-count)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good point. You can now enter a country as a relocation target.

Comment: I tried today to enter 'Denmark' and I get the same error aforementioned. Has this policy been reverted?